# C++ (gcc) dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/libssl.1.1.dylib

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, dynamic-linking

I am trying to link to a dynamic library on MacOs using gcc (C++). When I compile, there are no issues. But when I try running the program, this is what I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/libssl.1.1.dylib
```

I haven't moved the library from its directory, so I have no idea how to fix this. What should I do? (If you need more information, let me know as I would be happy to provide it)

Comment: Is libssl.1.1 installed into your system, or placed beside your executable? (it needs to be somewhere the dynamic-linker / executable can find, when ran)

Comment: @AdamWilhelm its beside my executable. Where should I put it?

Comment: Okay. Will it could be a multitude of issues at this point. Try `otool -L <executable_name_here>` to see what libs its linking against

Comment: Read [Friday Q&A 2009-11-06: Linking and Install Names](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html). Old, but worth reading.

Comment: @AdamWilhelm this is the output:@loader_path/libssl.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 902.1.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)

Comment: I'm a Linux guy, so I don't have many Mac-specific answers, BUT, I'd bet on the loader path being resolved wrong. (IE, the @ loader_path should be resolved to your executable directory as the library is in the same directory). Try to link against an absolute path to the library. If that works, then search up on alternatives to @ loader_path, namely, @ executable_path or @ rpath. On linux, rpath solves all of my linking issues so it looks like a good option to me.

Comment: Checkout @zrzka link above as it describes the difference between them. Also checkout this link as its a comparison between them: https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath . Finally, checkout `install_name_tool -change <library> <updated-library>` if you want to fiddle with the linker paths on the command line.